# Expire models in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a simple paste-bin in Ruby on Rails, which will have an expire-feature. With this, people can select a date when the paste will be deleted automatically. How can I implement this? I was thinking of a `cronjob`, but maybe there is a more platform-independent way, by defining this in the model itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cron` will work fine. You can make a `Rake` task that performs the actual deletions, and then trigger that from `cron`.

Alternatively, you could keep the data forever and simply quit showing any records that have expiration dates in the past.

Comment: I haven't thought of the second option. That one is actually greater than great! It will be more HTTP'ish, since I can use the right status-codes for permanently deleted resources, and some more things. Thanks!

Comment: And it's also good for spam-recognation if I keep all spam-pastes in the DB. A paste-bin is namely a spammer's-heaven ;)

Comment: you may also want to check out the whenever gem, see http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby